# How to change the color of these bars? I'm using an Excel API for Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, microsoft-excel

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(range);
      var chart = sheet.charts.add("ColumnClustered", dataRange, "Rows");
      chart.axes.valueAxis.minorUnit = 0.2;

      // chart.axes.valueAxis.format.font.

      //                12%
      //                +--+
      //                |  |
      // Acima da barra |  |
      chart.series.getItemAt(0).set({
        // format: { line: { color: 'black', weight: 10}},
        gapWidth: 2,
        dataLabels: {
          format: { font: { name: "Arial", size: 12, bold: false, color: "black" } }
        }
      });

      // chart.format.fill.setSolidColor("orange")

      chart.load('items')

      console.log(`>> ${chart.series.getItemAt(0)}`);

      chart.legend.visible = false;
      chart.dataLabels.format.font.size = 15;
      chart.dataLabels.format.font.color = "black";
      chart.axes.categoryAxis.format.fill.setSolidColor("white");
      chart.series.add();

      chart.axes.valueAxis.majorGridlines.visible = false;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Após muitos teste eu descobri como fazer:

```
chart.series.getItemAt(0).format.fill.setSolidColor("black")
```